# SQL this problem the table is blank but stored procedure while successfully

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem: there is a problem with this stored procedure which completes successfully, but the table is all column null the table is empty but the stored procedure while successful.

```
USE [database]   
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[exampleprocedur]    Script Date: 1.11.2018 17:32:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[exampleprocedur]
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [database].dbo.exampletable

    CREATE TABLE #examplecode 
    (
         colon1 VARCHAR(120),
         colon2 VARCHAR(120),
         colon3 VARCHAR(120),
         colon4 VARCHAR(120),
         colon5 VARCHAR(120),
         colon6 VARCHAR(120),
         colon7 VARCHAR(120),
         colon8 DECIMAL(28, 5),
         colon9 DECIMAL(28,5)
    )

    INSERT INTO #examplecode 
        SELECT
             a.colon1_no, a.colon2_no, a.colon3, '', '', '', '',
             a.colon8, a.colon9 
         FROM
             [database2].dbo.expr a (nolock) 
         WHERE
             colon2_no = '100'  
         ORDER BY
             a.colon3  

    SELECT * 
    INTO #examplecode2 
    FROM
        (SELECT
             b.colon3, b.colon11, b.colon12 
         FROM
             [database2].dbo.mmm b 
         WHERE
             colon11 IN ('ver1', 'ver2', 'ver3', 'ver4') 
             AND EXISTS (SELECT a.colon3 FROM #examplecode a 
                         WHERE a.colon3 = b.colon3)) tablom
    PIVOT
        (MAX(colon12)
            FOR colon11 IN ([ver1],[ver2],[ver3],[ver4])
        ) pivottablom

    UPDATE a 
    SET a.colon4 = b.colon4,
        a.colon5 = b.colon5,
        a.colon6 = b.zx,
        a.colon7 = b.zy 
    FROM 
        #examplecode a, #examplecode2 b 
    WHERE
        a.colon3 = b.colon3

    UPDATE a 
    SET a.colon2 = b.colon2_adi,
        a.colon1 = b.colon1_adi 
    FROM
        #examplecode a, [database2].dbo.mlz_colon1_colon2 b 
    WHERE
        a.colon2 = b.colon2_no 
        AND a.colon1 = b.colon1_no 

    INSERT INTO [database].dbo.exampletable(ver1Kodu, ver2, Em, ver3, ver4, Tm)
        SELECT
            colon4, SUBSTRING(colon5, 1, 7), colon8, colon6, colon7, 1 
        FROM
            #examplecode 
        WHERE
            colon4 IN ('1000') AND colon9 != 0.00000

    UPDATE [database].dbo.exampletable 
    SET ver2 = REPLACE(ver2, 'x', ' X ');
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: You may need to provide sample data.

Comment: **TYPO** alert: it's a **column** - not a "colon" ....

Answer (score 1):

An execution of a stored procedure without an error doesn't mean it inserts data, it only means that there is no syntax error, in your code you are deleting all the data in exampletable and inserting happens with a where condition, so there is no data satisfying your condition hence nothing is inserted